# What is "realm" in IIS authentication and how is it related to SSL certificate parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, ssl, forms-authentication

I'm trying to implemented custom basic authentication [similar to this](http://custombasicauth.codeplex.com/) and one thing that confuses me is a concept of *realm*. For example, there's a moment when my module inserts some magic string into the reply:

```
void ReplyWithAuthHeader()
{
    HttpContext currentContext = HttpContext.Current;
    context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
    context.Response.AddHeader( "WWW-Authenticate",
       String.Format("Basic realm=\"{0}\"", "myname.mycompany.com"));
}
```

The site is assigned an SSL certicicate created with makecert utility and is "issued" to "myname.mycompany.com". The caller creates a request:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create( serverUrl );
CredentialCache cache = new CredentialCache();
cache.Add( new Uri( serverUrl ), "Basic", new NetworkCredential( "UserName", "password" ) );
request.Credentials = cache;
```

where `serverUrl` starts with `https://` and when the request is being processed by the server the server sends the "WWW-Authenticate" reply, then an exception is thrown on the client side with "Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine." text.

So clearly there's something wrong at SSL negotiation level and I can't fugure what it is. I guess it could be something dealing with the realm.

My question is - what is a *realm* and how is it related to the name of the party to which an SSL certificate was issued when a connection is made over SSL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer your question "what is a realm?", some copypasta from [RFC 2617](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617#section-1.2):

> The realm directive (case-insensitive) is required for all authentication schemes that issue a challenge. The realm value (case-sensitive), in combination with the canonical root URL (the absoluteURI for the server whose abs_path is empty; see section 5.1.2 of [2]) of the server being accessed, defines the protection space. These realms allow the protected resources on a server to be partitioned into a set of protection spaces, each with its own authentication scheme and/or authorization database. The realm value is a string, generally assigned by the origin server, which may have additional semantics specific to the authentication scheme. Note that there may be multiple challenges with the same auth-scheme but different realms.

As to your question how it is related to your SSL certificate: it isn't. The easiest way I can think of to figure out what's going wrong, is simply by accessing the URL in your browser. You should get a pretty clear description of the problem (hostname doesn't match the certificate, untrusted CA, expired, etc.).

Answer (score 5):

The realm indicates the scope that the client is authenticating for. A browser will cache the username, password and realm and re-send the credentials for any further server responses requiring authentication for that realm.

There's no relationship between SSL and what's going on with HTTP, if you've managed to negotiate a connection and send a request and get a response, SSL won't be your problem. You could just be trying to write to a connection that's been closed. In this instance I'd load the private key into Wireshark and take a closer look at what's going on at a protocol level, both TCP/IP and HTTP.